# CodeLite replacing accent by special characters

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, ide

I'm using CodeLite to develop my PHP applications, but this one has the annoying tendency to replace all my accents with special characters (this one: � or others like Ã©).
But UTF-8 encoding is selected in my CodeLite settings in Settings> Misc> Local Encoding> File font encoding.

I also tested in ISO 8859-1 or 15 but I still do not see the accents.

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you in advance and good day.

Comment: Have you contacted CodeLite support regarding this issue?

Comment: Switch to a windows or dos encoding.  It's a feature not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this problem with CodeLite.  Go to a command prompt, and type chcp with no parameters.  It will report your current code page; for me in the U.S., it is 437.  When I changed CodeLite to using Windows 437 instead of UTF-8, I started seeing the correct non-ASCII characters.

I incorrectly assumed that UTF-8 would provide me the broadest compatibility with non-ASCII and non-English characters.